# Evaluate $\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\cos x+\sin x+\sqrt{3})^2}=2\sqrt{3}\pi.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The problem is to evaluate the following definite integral:
$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\cos x+\sin x+\sqrt{3})^2}=2\sqrt{3}\pi.$$

I have failed in almost every way I tried, with the exception of substitution by $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ which leads to the integration of a rational function with annoying coefficients.

Is there any "good" way to address the problem, given that the result doesn't seem that complicated? I've also tried [this website](https://www.integral-calculator.com/), but the result it gave was far from satisfactory. Please help.

Comment: Expand out the square. You will get things that will simplify a lot with trig identities.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Like substituting $u=\sin x+\cos x$, won’t $x$ be a pretty complicated expression?

Comment: If you expand the square in the denominator, you will get something like $\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x) + 2\sin(x)\cos(x) + 2\sqrt{3}\sin(x) + 2\sqrt{3}\cos(x) + 3$.

Comment: For integrating $\frac{1}{(\sin(x) - a)^{2}}$ (a short u-sub away), Wolfram spits out an ugly but elementary answer, which you could use as a last resort.

Comment: For the integral you mentioned, do we still need to substitute some $u$ for $\tan (x/2)$ ?

Comment: That will probably make it easier to do, yes.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. I did know it's solvable through this kind of substitution, but here it leads to a rational function with unfriendly coefficients, as opposed to the simple result. So as I've mentioned, I'm looking for another simpler way.

Comment: Are you interested in a computation using Complex Analysis?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sure! The approach is not limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let$$R(x,y)=\frac1{\left(x+y+\sqrt3\right)^2};$$then you want to compute $\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$. Define\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac1zR\left(\frac{z+1/z}2,\frac{z-1/z}{2i}\right)\\&=\frac{2iz}{\left(z^2+(1+i)\sqrt3z+i\right)^2}\\&=\frac{2iz}{\bigl((z-\alpha)(z-\beta)\bigr)^2},\end{align}with$$\alpha=\left(\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)(1+i)\quad\text{and}\quad\beta=-\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)(1+i).$$Then\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}R(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta&=\frac1i\int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,\mathrm dz\\&=2\pi\operatorname{res}_{z=\alpha}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)\\&=2\pi\sqrt3.\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

Note

\begin{align}
 I(a)=&\int_0^\pi \frac{dt}{(\cos t+a)^2} =
-\frac d{da}\int_0^\pi \frac{dt}{\cos t+a}\\
=&-\frac d{da} \frac\pi{\sqrt{a^2-1}}=\frac{\pi a}{(a^2-1)^{3/2}}
\end{align}

and apply it to evaluate

\begin{align} &\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\cos x+\sin x+\sqrt{3})^2}\\
= &\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\sqrt2\cos (x-\frac\pi4)+\sqrt{3})^2}\\
= &\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(\cos t+\sqrt{\frac32})^2}
 =I\left(\sqrt{\frac32}\right)=2\sqrt3\pi
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following identities:
$$\sin 2\theta\equiv\frac{2\tan \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}$$
$$\cos 2\theta\equiv\frac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{1+\tan^2 \theta}$$
And in your question then use the substitution $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$, as you did.

Persevere and it should work.